Why is hot water coming from cold water taps for a minute, then cooling off?
This problem came on gradually over about two months time.  There has been no changes to my plumbing for years. I thought it was likely the water heater so I replaced it with a new one, problem continues.
The temperature is set on A and the outside air is 75 day 45 night.  My water pressure is 72 PSI.  My cold taps run cold for 20 seconds, then hot for 40 seconds, then cold again.  When I say hot I mean hot, not warm.  It seems, hot water is going back up the cold water pipe from the heater to the house.
My plumber thinks it could be the mix valve on the bidet.  I have a mix valve on the shower and one on the bidet.  I was able to isolate the shower mix valve but the problem continues.  I have ordered a cartridge for the bidet.  In the meantime, I'd love to hear any other thoughts about what might be the problem.

Specify the model

The heater inlet being hot is normal.  When you heat cold water, it expands.  It can't go further along the hot pipes, because everything is shut off.  Therefore, it expands into the cold (inlet) pipe.  It may push water out of the house, past the meter.
Do you have an expansion tank?  It would normally be installed on the inlet for exactly this reason.  The expansion should push water into the expansion tank.  When you turn on the hot water, it will draw from the expansion tank before the outside.
If you do not have an expansion tank, it would make sense to add one.
If you already have an expansion tank, the plumber should examine it.  Perhaps it's faulty and needs replaced.
Have you checked water pressure?  High or low could cause problems.  Note that pressure problems may be a result of things outside the house.
If you have a pressure reducing valve, it may be malfunctioning.
Do you have a backflow preventer?  A backflow preventer without an expansion tank would be especially problematic.  Also, this is another thing that could be malfunctioning.  A backflow preventer would prevent expansion from pushing water out of the house.
Do you have a recirculation system?  Some of those work by pushing tepid water from the hot pipe back into the cold pipe.  That kind can be installed near the fixture, e.g. under the sink.  Pictures of the pipes could help get that diagnosed.
This is probably not an exhaustive list but gives you some things to check.

I do not have an expansion tank.   Never had one and never had this issue.  No backflow preventer or check valves either.  There was a circulation system, I believe, that had been disconnected some time before we bought the house 6 years ago.  My pressure is 72#s at the heater.  Today, when testing the heater pressure, noticed that that pressure would come back up to 72 in about 10 seconds with the Cold water valve to the heater at shutoff.

I know this valve is good because I used it to turn off the water when I replaced the heater.  This, to my mind, means the cold/house water supply is pressurizing the hot water lines, pushing water backwards through the heater until the pressure equalizes, thus heating up the cold intake to the heater.  So, since there have been no changes to the plumbing. it does kind of make sense that it could be a mix valve cartridge leaking pressure from one side to the other.  Before I put in an expansion tank or check valves, I think I'll wait to see if the bidet cartridge solves the issue.

This will be the third cartridge for the bidet, and though it is an expensive $800 bidet, I'm beginning to think it's a piece of crap!  Pun intended!
